Handshakes Combinatorics Problem
Problem: Eight couples attend a party. Every gentleman will shake hands with all the other guests except his own wife. Ladies do not shake hands with other ladies. Find out the total number of handshakes.
My Attempt: The total number of handshakes without restriction is ${16 \choose 2}$. The number of handshakes between couples is 8, while the number of handshakes between the ladies is ${8 \choose 2}$. So, the total number of handshakes is ${16 \choose 2}- 8- {8 \choose 2}=\boxed{84}.$
Can someone spot the mistake in my solution (if there's any)? I think that my answer was correct but it was marked wrong.

Each man shakes $14$ people's hands.  Each woman shakes $7$.  That makes $8\times (14+7)=168$ in total.  Of course, we are counting each handshake twice, so we must divide by $2$. Just as another way to see it.

Thank you for that neater solution! Is my attempt valid?

Sure.  I just wanted to give an alternate method to confirm the result.  I'll post it below, for completeness.

There are two types of handshakes: those between two of the eight men, of which there are $\binom{8}{2}$, and those between men and women, of which there are $8 \cdot 7$ since each of the eight men shakes hands with the seven women other than his wife.  Thus, there are $$\binom{8}{2} + 8 \cdot 7 = 84$$ handshakes, as you found.

Thank you! Is my attempt valid?

@zwrqwrok "Is my attempt valid" : Yes, your approach is also perfectly valid.  Further, your question raises a very subtle underlying question.  Suppose that your answer, which is numerically equivalent to the accurate answer, was somehow invalid (which it is not).  Then, after you found the invalid aspect of your analysis, you would then have to explain why the invalid analysis resulted (somehow) in the same numerical solution.

Yes, your solution is correct.  Like lulu, I provided an alternate solution to confirm your result.

As an alternate method to confirm the solution:
Note that each man shakes hands with $14$ people, and each woman shakes hands with $7$ people.  Adding those up gives $$8\times (14+7)=168$$
Of course we have counted each handshake twice, so we must divide by $2$, giving $\boxed {84}$, and confirming your result.
